# How do I attach a stylesheet?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, stylesheet

ok for anyone else experiencing this in future it was a permissions issue with iis i had to set permissions on the whole tree for the style sheet to render

How do I attach a stylesheet?  I've tried the usual way:

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="../../Content/Site.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
```

with various file paths.  I've also tried with vb url.content scripts.  For some reason nothing I try is displayed in the browser.

I get various results:

- stylesheet cannot be found
- sometimes firebug only shows the html written

What else could be the problem?

Its attached to the master file, so i dont know what else is wrong here.
[image]

Comment: Is this free verse? Would I be desecrating art if I formatted it?

Comment: This looks more like a haiku than a question. Please state your question clearly.

Comment: I think he accidently the important parts of the question.

Comment: poetry.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ah, @Joel Coehoorn, you saved me from my ethical quandary.

Comment: i just want my stylesheet to work but all the ways ive tried and they dont show up im not sure what more information i can give you except im using visual basic 2010 with a mvc app

Comment: come on im fairly new to this and dont usually have issues attaching stylesheets im sure you all came across simple annoying issues when you all starting learning :D

Answer (score 3):

What you need to remember with an MVC application is that often your URL's will not match up with your actual file system.

Assuming that you have a folder structure set up similar to the defaults:

```
/Content/
/Content/Site.css
/Views/
/Views/Home/
/Views/Home/index.aspx
/Views/Shared/
/Views/Shared/site.master
```

When you add the style declaration to your master page, your relative path makes sense:

```
../../Content/Site.css
```

> Go two folders up from where I am now, and then down into `/content` to find `Site.css`.

However, when you're viewing the page in your browser, that relative path is no longer valid:

http://www.example.com/Home/

Where's two folders down from this? Worse still, a deep link:

http://www.example.com/blogs/2010/11/23/My-posting

This will try and look for a folder called Content in the /blogs/2010/ folder.

You have two options:

1. Use an absolute link: `href="/Content/Site.css"` this will tell the browser to always start from the root of your site.
2. Use the application root link: `href="~/Content/Site.css"` - which, if the link is in a control that is set to `runat="server"` should be corrected at runtime to point to the application root.

---

**Responding to comment**

Ok, but we're getting somewhere now:

Looking at the URL you posted, on your development machine you're running this site as an application under the root? So when you request the site, you're going to: http://localhost/pulse/ ?

So what do you see in your browser if you request http://localhost/pulse/Content/Site.css ?

What does the Routes collection look like in your Global.asax.cs file? Is there something in there that is interfering with the /Content/ folder?

Comment: i tried these before with "/Content/Site.css" i get <title>IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>
5<style type="text/css"> and with "~/Content/Site.css" i get The resource from this URL is not text: http://localhost/pulse/Content/Site.css

Comment: i dont understand it it does exist and it picks up my html

Comment: +1  Its either a permissions thing, or the CSS file is not where you are looking for it.

Comment: css is where it should be and i gave permissions to iis but i guess im not getting anywhere with this right now :D but thankyou for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is *Asp.net MVC*. **Don't use relative file paths** because paths are mostly related to routes. Use `Url.Content()` helper instead.

```
<link rel="StyleSheet"
      href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen" />
```

Comment: this is what i tried to use from the start but it still doesnt work i get no error code when i use this

Comment: @sam: Then we're missing something here. Can you use exactly the line I've provided and tell us what do see **exactly** in firebug after you load your page. I suppose your application root is `localhost/pulse/` and not at root namely `localhost/`...

Answer (score 1):

"You can also drag the file from Solution Explorer to the head element of the page in Source view, or drag the file from Solution Explorer and drop it anywhere on the page in Design view."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398932.aspx

**UPDATE:**

Check this post: http://forums.asp.net/p/1469427/3399574.aspx

The syntax provided by Robert should work.

Comment: got this in firebug i tried loads of different paths multiple times and this is a new application

Comment: The resource from this URL is not text: http://localhost/pulse/Content/Site.css sorry keep pressing enter bar for new line

Comment: Can you provide a snippet from the master page and an overview of your directory structure?

Comment: what happens if you remove the link tag from the master page and try dragging the CSS file from Solution Explorer into the head tag in the source code window?

Comment: this is what it says The resource from this URL is not text: localhost/pulse/Content/Site.css

Comment: Try it outside of Firebug because this may be a bug http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2063